# kendo grid export pdf all pages doesn't work, only the current page is exported

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I'm working with c# asp.net mvc,
I'm trying to export all pages included in the grid but only the current page was exported.
I follow this demo but no luck :
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/pdf-export

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/pdf-export#export-of-all-pages

in kendo grid add this line - **.Pdf(pdf => pdf.AllPages())**

Comment: thank you , But ,I have already this line. 
Pdf(pdf => pdf
            .AllPages()
            .AvoidLinks()
            .PaperSize("A4")
            .Scale(0.8)
            .Margin("2cm", "1cm", "1cm", "1cm")
            .Landscape()
            .RepeatHeaders()
            .TemplateId("page-template")
            .FileName("Liste.pdf")

Comment: can you provide your kendo version??

Comment: this is the version: 2017.1.118

Comment: See this example link - http://dojo.telerik.com/@PMcDonou/ihumI/5
and also check and add this JS link - <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>
try this

Comment: It's always worthwhile at least summarising the contents of a link if you post one.  Just in case the link goes dead and someone re-visits this answer in the future.

Comment: thank you @PrakashGupta  ! i check the Js , but the problem persists!

Comment: @PrakashGupta thank you !
 i couldn't paste my code but it's totaly like the code in this link : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/pdf-export